# Unexcepted message is displaying

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, winforms, msgbox

By mistake i just code a `Nested Msgbox` but it gives me an interesting output as explained below, can anyone give me the reason for this?

The snippet i had tried was

```
MsgBox(MsgBox(MsgBox("Inner") & "Middle") & "Outer")
```

it gives the **output** as

- `Inner '<--- displays first`
- `1Middle'<--- displays second`
- `1Outer'<--- displays last`

My **Question** is this:

Why '1' is comming? Does `msgbox` **returning** a `Boolean` value?

Answer (score 0):

Ya Definitely `msgbox` is returns an integer value. but not a `Boolean`.

As per [microSoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) explanation Depending on the `msgbox Style` the return value varies as following

```
OK     1
Cancel 2
Abort  3
Retry  4
Ignore 5
Yes    6
No     7
```